# Filling/Highlighting the cells according to the numeric value

Tags: microsoft-excel-2016

I would like to highlight a series of cells based on the numeric value present in certain cell (please refer to attached SS for more details.

[Sheet 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F6Sp0.png)
[Sheet 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LvT59.png)
Basically, if the value in e.g. Sheet1!A4 = 1, than based on the value in Sheet1!C4 (in this case it's 4) highlight the cells in Sheet2  of the relevant assignee (in this case Assignee 2 should have 4 highlighted cells). I am trying to figure out this for quite some time without success and I would appreciate any help or a guide (tried to combine Index, Match & Index and ROW functions but still it's hard to get the required result)

Answer (score 0):

When the sort of Assingee in Sheet1 is exactly same as Assingee in Sheet2. Please try the Conditional Formatting.

Select a range from B2 in Sheet2, which is big enough to highlight needed cells. Such as from B2 to N9.

Go to Conditional Formatting > New Rule > Use a formula to ··· > enter the formula `=IF(COLUMN(B2)-COLUMN($B2)<Sheet1!$C3,TRUE)` > Format > Choose the color to fill > OK.

The following picture is the screenshot of Manager Rules in Sheet2.
[image]

The picture below is the data in Sheet1.

[image]

Comment: Hi @Emily and thanks for you comment. The issue  is that you are not making an evaluation whether something is or "is not" in the Scope (if the InsScope value is equal to 1 than the task should be reflected in the sheet_2, if the value is equal to 0, task should/highlighting should not be reflected. Also, several tasks can be assigned to the same assignee, so we cannot "lock" the assignee order :/.